How does a bacterium capable of tomosynthesis work? Would it be similar to cellular respiration?
I'm working on a speculative evolution project and well I would like some bacteria that is capable of using heat as a source of energy, as I understand it what generates heat is like temperature differentiation but I don't know what else there, I was wondering if it would be something similar to cellular respiration (Since I study medicine I know how that works) but I don't know if it is exactly the same because oxygen is a molecule and here we talk about energy, if you can answer my question I would be grateful. I do warn you that the bacteria I'm making lives in hydrothermal sources

Heat is energy; wht you probably want to extract from heat is free energy. But the only way to extract free energy from heat is to use a the temperature difference between a hot source and a cold sink: and given that most bacteria are rather small, I don't really see how you could have one end of a bacterium at a higher temperature than the other end. This does not mean that the bacterium cannot use the heat for other purposes, for example for the purpose of accelerating some chemical reactions.

Yes, I know that (I don't know if I explained myself well because I'm using Google Translate since my English is very poor) but I read that it is theoretically possible, the thing is that I don't know how, if through proteins that change their composition due to temperature or as I said with the subject of mitochondria, although it is not the same, I mean that they have like two membranes, one internal and one external, which help the electron chain

Alas, AlexP is correct. You can't extract energy that is in the form of ambient temperature. Think of it like pressure. If you're in a high pressure environment, you can't do anything with the pressure unless you also have a low pressure environment to connect it to. You need a gradient. There is no known mechanism for converting ambient heat into other forms of energy. That would be reverse entropy.

So why when I was looking for information on the subject did it say that it is possible within what is possible? I mean, I read that theoretically it can work and it is possible in microorganisms without the presence of light

You have probably read about Anthonie W.J. Muller's hypothesis of thermosynthetic micro-organisms. That hypothesis is perfectly within the realm of what is physicaly possible; the difference between Muller's hypothesis and this question is that Muller speaks about using thermal $\rightarrow$cycling$\leftarrow$ to extract free energy. If the organism lives in a place which cycles between two different temperatures then yes the bacterium or whatever can indeed use some sort of phase transition or some other mechanism to extract energy.

Closest thing i know this exists is : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent
Where the energy carrier of choice is hot sulphuric water..
There is also bacteria that lifes in the earths crust- and thus also in the old continental plates going down.. of course there will be heat that sterilizes. But then .. life might get weird about that given time.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthermophile
There is also radioactivity eating fungi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiotrophic_fungus
What your system needs to extract the heat produced chemical energy or just directly energy - is a sort of "gradient". A energy differential, that allows to condense that brownian motion into stable, structural state, without getting tangled up and destroyed. In other words- it would ideally have some sort of fridge setup. With a hot and cold end.. one end it cooks, the other end eats what the other cooks up.
How to do that? No idea..
